# segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, netbeans-7

I am trying get a mandelbrot image clearly with the sequential programming in C++, but I am getting a segmentation fault during runtime. I have no idea about the seg. fault, but my program is perfectly compiling with no errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int file_write(unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    unsigned int **color = NULL;
    FILE *fractal = fopen("mandelbrot_imageSequential.ppm","w+");
    if(fractal != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fractal,"P6\n");
        fprintf(fractal,"# %s\n", "Mandelbrot_imageSequential.ppm");
        fprintf(fractal,"%d %d\n", height, width);
        fprintf(fractal,"40\n");
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        unsigned int R = 0, G = 0, B = 0;
        for(x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            for(y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                R = (color[y][x]*10);
                G = 255-((color[y][x]*10));
                B = ((color[y][x]*10)-150);
                if(R == 10)
                    R = 11;
                if(G == 10)
                    G = 11;
                if(B == 10)
                    B = 11;
                putc(R, fractal);
                putc(G, fractal);
                putc(B, fractal);
            }
        }
        fclose(fractal);
    }
    return 0;
}
int method(int x, int y, int height, int width, double min_re, double max_re, double min_im, double max_im, int max_iterations)
{
    double threshold = 4;
    double x_factor = (max_re-min_re)/(width-1);
    double y_factor = (max_im-min_im)/(height-1);
    double c_im = max_im - y*y_factor;
    double c_re = min_re + x*x_factor;
    double Z_re = c_re, Z_im = c_im;
    unsigned int col = 0;
    for(unsigned n = 0; n < max_iterations; ++n)
    {
        double Z_re2 = Z_re*Z_re, Z_im2 = Z_im*Z_im;
        if(Z_re2 + Z_im2 > threshold)
        {
            col = n;
            break;
        }
        Z_im = 2 * Z_re * Z_im + c_im;
        Z_re = Z_re2 - Z_im2 + c_re;
    }
    return col;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned int max_iterations;
    unsigned int **color = NULL;
    int x,y;
    double threshold;
    double min_re;
    double max_re;
    double min_im;
    double max_im;
    unsigned int NUM_OF_THREADS;
    if(argc != 10)
    {
        printf("There is an error in the input given.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        height = atoi(argv[1]);
        width = atoi(argv[2]);
        max_iterations = atoi(argv[3]);
        min_re = atof(argv[4]);
        max_re = atof(argv[5]);
        min_im = atof(argv[6]);
        max_im = atof(argv[7]);
        threshold = atoi(argv[8]);
        NUM_OF_THREADS = atoi(argv[9]);
    }
    color = (unsigned int**)malloc(height*sizeof(unsigned int*));
    printf("height = %d\twidth = %d\tmaximum_iterations = %d\tminimum_x-value = %.2f\tmaximum_x-value = %.2f\tminimum_y-value = %.2f\tmaximum_y-value = %.2f\tthreshold_value = %.2f\tno. of threads = %d\t\n",height,width,max_iterations,min_re,max_re,min_im,max_im,threshold,NUM_OF_THREADS);
    for(x = 0; x < height; x++)
    {
        color[x] = (unsigned int*)malloc(width*sizeof(unsigned int));
    }
    time_t ts,te;
    time(&ts);
    method(x,y,height,width,min_re,max_re,min_im,max_im,max_iterations);
    time(&te);
    double diff = difftime(te,ts);
    file_write(width, height);
    printf("Total Time elapsed: %f\n",diff);
    return 0;
}
```

How to correct this segmentation fault?

Comment: Let your debugger find the segfault spot.

Comment: I could spot one problem in your `file_write`: you never allocate memory for your `unsigned int **color` or rather, you didn't pass the `color` out of your main to the function.

Comment: This variable: `unsigned int **color = NULL;` is the where the segfault is happening.  You don't initialize it and yet you dereference it in the code.

Comment: Seriously broken indentation. :|

Comment: This doesn’t look the least bit like C++ code. Also, what unwind said.

Answer (score 2):

At least one problem is in the file_write function.

1. `unsigned int **color = NULL;`
2. `R = (color[y][x]*10);`

I assume the color should be an input parameter.

Comment: can i know what is the solution for this seg fault?

Comment: Sure. 1. `int file_write(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int **color)
{...}`, 2. `file_write(width, height, color);`. But there is another problem. The color is allocated in the main, not initialized and not used anywhere, i.e. the function `file_write` saves something.

Comment: now i try to run it on C compiler instead of running it C++, it is showing an error and note

> error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

> note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

Comment: i know that seg fault mainly occurs due to improper memory allocation, that is trying to access a variable which is not allocated...

Comment: change `for(unsigned n = 0; n < max_iterations; ++n)` to `unsigned n; for(n = 0; n < max_iterations; ++n)`

Comment: its not working for me... now i am getting segmentation fault (core dumped), i know what it means? but i dont know where it tries to access the -(not allocated space)

Comment: do u have any other solution for this problem, because i am helpless regarding this seg fault

Comment: I pointed you a 1st problem which I mentioned. Also pointed you how to resolve the compilation error. Have you fixed both of these points? Another issue that `y` is not initialized in `main`. I don't know either it affects on the segfault or does not.

Comment: i have found the segfault where it occurs, it was in the line R = (color[y][x]*10);
but i should try to allocate the memory for the color, because it trying to access the non existed space

Comment: Please look to the my 1st comment on this answer, It starts with "Sure. 1.". It fixes the segfault. Have you changed your code as written in this comment?

Comment: its running, but i am getting a wrong image file with only green color, not the mandelbrot image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10502/discussion-between-visanio-learner-and-megabyte1024)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux machine do the following :

```
$ulimit -c unlimited
```

Then run the code. Notice a core.[pid] file is generated. fire up gdb like following

```
$gdb ./your_app core.[pid]
```

It will take you the statement where segfault occurred. issue a "backtrace" command in gdb prompt to see the call hierarchy.

Remember compiling with "-g" flag to get more verbose gdb output.

Comment: what arguments you have provided to gdb? are you in the directory where your binary resides? have you verified the existence of "core" file?

Comment: and als there is a file with huge amount size core filename

Comment: then just type $gdb ./<your binary name>  <your core file name>

Comment: and also do not put "$" infront of your command. its just denote a shell prompt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10499/discussion-between-aftnix-and-visanio-learner)

Comment: now i see the core. it was generated by my command line arguments, also it says a warning

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems with your code:

1. You allocate memory for the `color` array but then use a *different* `color` inside `file_write()` which is initialized to `NULL`.

   You need to pass the first `color` as an argument to `file_write()`:

   ```
   int main(...)
   {
       ...
       file_write(color, width, height);
       printf("Total Time elapsed: %f\n",diff);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   And declare the other `color` as an argument to `file_write()`:

   ```
   int file_write(unsigned int **color, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
   {
       /* unsigned int **color = NULL; // Removed */
      ...
   ```
2. You're only calling `method()` once and not storing anything into `color`. You need to call it in a loop. Something similar to:

   ```
   /* Untested */
   for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
       for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
           color[y][x] = method(x,y,height,width,min_re,max_re,min_im,max_im,max_iterations);
       }
   }
   ```

Then, of course, you should check the return values of `malloc()`, `fopen()`, `fprintf()`, `fclose()`, ... , and check that the input variables have reasonable values and so on.

I also noticed that you're passing `width` and `height` in different order to `file_write()` and `method()`. To avoid future headaches, I would change  the `method()` function to `method(x, y, width, height)` so that the horizontal and vertical arguments are passed in the same order.